# Unable to debug Azure webjobs - the webjob processes do not show in the "Attach to process" dialog

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013, remote-debugging, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

Visual Studio 2013 update 3.  I have deployed several Webjobs to Azure, both manually (upload a bundle via the portal) and also published directly from Visual Studio.  The webjobs I am testing with are set to run "Continuous" and have code that runs inside a while(true) {} loop; so the process never ends.  The webjobs are functioning properly and I see their runtime output in the Webjobs dashboard log output screen.

I've enabled remote debugging on the website.  When I select Debug, Attach to process, the webjob process names never show on the list.  All I see are the remote debugger processes and w3wp.exe.

[image: Attach to process dialog box]

Ideas?

Comment: Is the job failing to start? Maybe the process starts and dies immediately. Since you tagged the question with webjobs SDK, did you set the connection strings? Check the logs in the webjobs dashboard

Comment: @VictorHurdugaci - No the job runs fine - I am glad you asked this because I left that info out.  I updated my question.

Answer (score 9):

Instead of attaching to SITENAME.azurewebsites.net, try to attach to SITENAME.scm.azurewebsites.net. Use same credentials as for the regular debugging connection. WebJobs run under a different context (Kudu), hence the different endpoint.

Comment: This thing did the trick for me. It was attaching the whole thing to a domain name and didn't work